# массовая обработка форм php

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно, что бы на странице с товарами, которые грузятся и базы данных, была возможность изменять эти столбцы товаров прямо на странице с ними. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как это реализовать, ведь если я просто сделаю одни формы с placeholder'ами обработчик обработает все формы, но мне нужно чтобы обработались только затронутые.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант ajax. Назначить Вам нужное событие а потом отправлять ajax и обрабатывать на стороне сервера

Answer (score 1):

Из базы подгружаешь название в таблицу потом id как уникальный ключь отправляешь на другую страницу циклом прогоняеш в массив складываешь. прогоняешь уже в sql update

```
echo '<form method="post" action="www.php">';
echo '<div>';
echo'<table  cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">';
for ($tr=0; $tr<=$rows; $tr++){
echo'<tr>';

  if (isset($arr[$tr])){
    foreach ($arr[$tr] as $key => $value) {

  echo '<td style="width: 120px;" align="center">'.$value.' // название товара за место холдера


 <br><input type="text" name='.$key.'-'.$arr[$tr]['id'].' size="5"><br></div><br><button type="submit">Изменить</button>
   </td>';

}}
echo'</tr>';
}
echo'</table>';
echo '<br><button type="submit">Изменить</button>';
echo '</form>'; 
echo '</div>';
```